# jQuery GET/POST callback function not responding

Tags: jquery, post

I have this HTML:

```
<a href="#" class="btn" id="checkit">Verfügbarkeit prüfen</a>


 $("#checkit").on('click', function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                var expected_slug = $('#user_slug').val();
                $.post("/myUrl", {slug: expected_slug}, function(data){
                    console.log(data);
                });
                console.log("bal");
```

Why is console.log(data) not fired?
But console.log("bal") gets fired...

response is 200 and contains "true"

Comment: Put a breakpoint at console.log(data) in dev tools or firebug.  What is the return value of 'data'?

Comment: to debug use the `$.ajax` method and assign `success`,`error` and `complete` callbacks. This way you can see if there is an error or open your developer tools in chrome/ff/etc (hit f12) and see if you have any console errors. You can also watch the network traffic tab and see what the server is responding with. Additionally add logging to your server side code to observe what is happening there. As it stands you need more information for this issue.

Comment: Adding to what scrappedcola wrote, you should post the server code, ie. whatever code /myUrl contains. Without that, it's impossible to know for certain why you're not getting the expected result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use .done above jquery 1.5

```
$("#checkit").click(function() {

    var expected_slug = $('#user_slug').val();
    $.post("/myUrl", {slug: expected}).done(function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    });
    console.log("bal");

    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

because you are not enclosing it with a `<form>` tag

specify action too in your `$.post()` by adding in the settings as `type: POST` or  `type: GET`

Comment: Fail.  $.[b]post[/b] specifies the verb.

Comment: jQuery docs to $.post(): `Description: Load data from the server using a HTTP POST request.`

Comment: oops! $.post is immediately known as POST... I was thinking the $.ajax.. though they are similar....
 $.ajax({ url: YOUR_ACTION_FILE_URL, type: POST, data: $("#form").serialize(), success: function(){ $("form").append("success!"); } });